# Validate Responses to a Google Form from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

1. I have an array of "random codes" in a google spreadsheet which keeps getting updated.
2. I give out these random codes to public and they come to complete my survey in a google form
3. I need to validate the responses so that i know the response is authentic. So i ask the random code from the user (which i have earlier distributed among people) in the google form.
4. So when a user enters his random code in the google form, i need it to be validated against the codes available in the google spreadsheet and accept his input OR reject his input.

Is above possible?

If so how?

Thanks!

Comment: There are Forms addons which may be able to do this. I flagged this question to be migrated to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: I think **yes** it is possible and fairly simple.  Get your random codes into an array.  Then onFormSubmit in the spreadsheet you can use either values or named values from [formSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3) and `randomArray.indexOf()>-1`

Comment: Then will the user be alerted that his input is rejected? and can we give him another chance to enter it correctly?